# How can I make my Django App *do* something when I run the server?

Tags: python, django, scheduler

first question here.
I'm a beginner in Python and for my final project I'm making a scraping app in Django. When I run my server I want it to start a `BackgroundScheduler` that calls my scraping app every 10 minutes. Right now I have my Scheduler on a button but I don't want it to be on a button, I want it to work right when I run my server, is this possible?

What I've tried:

- writing my logic into apps.py then adding the appconfig to settings
  to INSTALLED_APPS but I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'finance_app.apps.FinanceAppConfig'; 'finance_app.apps' is not a package

- making an scheduler.py file where my logic lives and adding it to INSTALLED_APPS but still won't work

**apps.py with its logic**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django.apps import AppConfig

from finance_app.scraper import scrape


class FinanceAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'finance_app'

    def ready(self):
        print('Initializing scheduler')
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(scrape, 'interval', second=30)
        scheduler.start()
```

**The BackgroundScheduler that works:**

```
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(scrape, 'interval', second=30)
        scheduler.start()
```

**Scheduler inside my view that calls the scraper**

```
def scraper_view(request):
    scrape()

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(scrape, 'interval', minutes=10)
    scheduler.start()

    return redirect("../")
```

**Button with the view that I want to get rid of**

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><h2 class="subtitlu">
    <a href="{% url 'scraper' %}">Scrape News</a>
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use django celery to automate regular task. Refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWxYPq7Sc8A&t=484s&ab_channel=VeryAcademy) to learn more about celery and task scheduling.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm on windows and celery is not compatible with windows from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I have django_setup() in my scraper file and that's why it didn't work, also for future references, in ready() function from apps.py, if you have any imports other than AppConfig, import them inside your ready() function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'finance_app.apps.FinanceAppConfig'

Please look at the traceback where the error occured. Eg.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".\app\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from app import something
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

You can put the traceback here.

If it is an error after adding the app into settings.py INSTALLED_APPS, you should check the way you've added it. It should be only 'finance_app':

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'finance_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Yes it is added like that, just finance_app but the logic inside apps.py won't start, my app is working properly but this schedule thing is the problem.

Comment: If you are encountering an error ModuleNotFoundError, it is not possible to continue executing the code in ready() function. Please can you show the traceback?

Comment: I don't get an error if I only put 'finance_app' into settings, my app works, only the logic in apps.py doesn't start, the code in ready() doesn't start..

Comment: Which version of Python and Django do you use?